# How to make a detail view with fields that are toggled by the button?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

So far my best guess is to make an UpdateView and toggle the `editable` attribute when user presses the button. Is it a good approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing to the objects in question is toggling the value of that one field, I would suggest that there's no need to have an UpdateView. You can just add a simple POST form within your DetailView, including a toggle button, whose 'action' is a URL that toggles the 'editable' field.

In the DetailView definition, add a post() method, to handle the form submissions and actually change the value of the 'editable' field.

Comment: I am trying to make a DetailView for customer object with the 'EDIT' button. When the button is pressed the fields with customer data become editable. I am sorry, I should've explained it better